# AngularJS - Prevent submission of a form if it is invalid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-forms

I have created an isolated case of my issue:
http://plnkr.co/edit/6LXW5TG76LC9LNSrdpQC

Here is the code of the isolated case:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

    <head></head>

    <body ng-controller="ExampleController">
    
    <form name="form" ng-submit="submit()" novalidate>
        <input type="number" name="number" ng-model="number" required><br>
        <span ng-show="form.number.$error.required && form.number.$touched">Required<br></span>
        <span ng-show="form.number.$error.number">Not a number<br></span>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
        
        var App = angular.module('App', []);
        
        App.controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
        
        $scope.submit = function() {
            alert('send to server: ' + $scope.number);
        }
        
        });
        
        App.run();
        
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Basically, the example contains a number field, and beneath it are error messages that show when the input is invalid (empty or not a number).

But the form will still submit, and although the field value is set to 'undefined' if it is not valid, I would prefer a way of checking if the form is valid before sending to the server (the alert box in this example).

So my question is - In AngularJS, is there a way of checking if a form is valid from within a controller? Or another way to prevent a form from submitting if it is invalid?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Better do change in `ng-submit` expression to

```
ng-submit="form.$valid && submit()"
```

Best use of angular directive expression.

Comment: me likey this one the best, yes me do

Comment: @meffect clean & neat on UI itself..I used this almost in all of my forms..

Answer (score 5):

http://plnkr.co/edit/kqLUJpjt0n0anJxzm6en?p=preview

what you need is

```
if ($scope.form.$valid) {
    //submit to server
}
```

where `form` is form name

```
<form name="form"...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with **ng-disabled** directive

```
      <button type="submit" ng-disabled='number==null'>Submit</button>
```

In that way you can avoid adding additional code